# How to copy a file to Android's /system folder

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am running Android emulator (emulator version 30.5.5.0) and the avd: `Pixel_3a_API_30_x86` from AndroidStudio.
Using `adb.exe` (Android Debug Bridge) I try to copy a file from the Windows host to the emulated Android `/system/...` folder, but I haven't been able to after trying different things like [this tutorial](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-install-system-trusted-ca-android/#3-insert-certificate-into-system-certificate-store):

- I run the android emulator from the command line to specify the parameter `-writable-system`:

```
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator
emulator -avd Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 -writable-system
```

Then from another command-line window while the emulator is running:

```
cd C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

adb root
adb shell "mount -o rw,remount /"
'/dev/block/dm-0' is read-only

adb push MyFile.txt /system/etc/security/cacerts
```

Then I get the error:
ERROR:

```
MyFile.txt: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 0.1 MB/s (950 bytes in 0.011s)
adb: error: failed to copy 'MyFile.txt' to '/system/etc/security/cacerts/MyFile.txt': remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system
```

How can I copy the file from Windows to Android `/system` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial in the link was missing some commands and [the web page](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-install-system-trusted-ca-android/#3-insert-certificate-into-system-certificate-store) was not updated with the [latest version from GitHub](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/edit/main/docs/src/content/howto-install-system-trusted-ca-android.md).

Here is the final sequence (for API LEVEL > 28):

```
adb root
adb shell avbctl disable-verification
adb reboot
adb root
adb remount

adb push MyFile.txt /system/etc/security/cacerts
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `adb root && adb remount` first.